Properly integrating JSDoc and type definitions for Deno and JSR
I'm working on a JavaScript codebase designed for both Deno and browsers. We're adding documentation and types to publish it on JSR, but I've hit some roadblocks.

JSDoc
Using JSDoc for @param and @returns doesn't work with deno doc or JSR - they ignore the types, likely because they rely on .d.ts files for type information. This seems limiting for *.js files but might be a technical constraint (my educated guess is, it's not really JSDoc but TSDoc, which makes sense).

.d.ts Files
I tried using .d.ts files following https://docs.deno.com/runtime/fundamentals/typescript/, however:

Comments in the source and .d.ts seem mutually exclusive in deno doc, forcing me to move all comments in .d.ts, leaving the source undocumented.
While the editor’s language server recognizes the .d.ts types for imports (a main.js, but still fails on add.js), deno check fails on both main.js and add.js with errors like: error: TS7006 [ERROR]: Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type. (same for b).



Questions:

How can I make deno check work with @ts-self-types for both the source (add.js) and the importer (main.js)?
Is there any way to make JSDoc types work directly with deno doc and JSR without .d.ts files?


I recommend creating JSR issue for any JSDoc issues with it: https://github.com/jsr-io/jsr/issues/new

Related issue: https://github.com/jsr-io/jsr/issues/494
